# Using IO within a QuickCheck property test?

Tags: haskell, io, quickcheck, hspec

I'm currently writing a Haskell library to replace a closed-source 3rd party command line application. This 3rd party CLI has a spec that I've replicated, but the actually binary allows much more permissive inputs than the spec.

I'd like to be able to generate inputs using `QuickCheck`, then compare the result of a function in my library to the stdout of the 3rd party CLI app. The part I'm getting stuck on is how to introduce IO within a property test.

Here's the code I have so far:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T
import Test.Hspec
import Test.Hspec.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck

-- This function lives in my library, this is just a sample
-- the actual function does things but is still pure, and has the type Text -> Int
exampleCountFuncInModule :: T.Text -> Int
exampleCountFuncInModule t = T.length t

-- contrived example generator
genSmallString :: Gen T.Text
genSmallString = do 
    smallList <- T.pack <$> resize 2 (listOf1 arbitraryASCIIChar)
    pure ("^" `T.append` smallList)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hspec $ do
        prop "some property" $ do
            verbose $ forAll genSmallString $ \xs -> (not . T.null) xs ==> do
                let myCount = exampleCountFuncInModule xs
                -- Want to run external program here, and read the result as an Int
                let otherProgramCount = 2
                myCount == otherProgramCount
```

I found that QuickCheck has an `ioProperty`, and that seems like it might be what I want, I'm just not sure how to fit that into what I already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured this out, I used this:

```hs
test :: Text -> IO Bool 
test t = do
    (exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) <- callCmd $ "bin/cliTool" :| [Text.unpack t]
    let cliCount = read stdOut :: Int
    let myCount = countOfThingsInString t
    return $ cliCount == myCount
```

Then in my hspec tests:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    hspec $ do
       describe "tests" $ do
            prop "test IO" $ do
                verbose $ forAll arbitrarySmallSpecifier (ioProperty . test)
```